# (Python Selenium) Trying to figure out how to pull text from a fieldset listed as Div ID's with traceResult

Tags: python, selenium

Been having a bit of trouble trying to pull the specific text from a fieldset.

I want to be able to pull the "12/9/2021"; but it is part of a fieldset where every entry is some variation of traceResult:j_idt# and if I try to reference this it errors out. I have also tried using `[contains(text(), 'Estimated')]` but that didn't seem to do the trick either.

```
<div id="traceResult:j_idt48" rendered="rendered" class="trRow row">
  <div id="traceResult:j_idt49" rendered="rendered" class="large-6 columns">
    <label>Delivery Date (Estimated)</label>
  </div>
  <div id="traceResult:j_idt53" rendered="rendered" class="large-6 columns ">
     12/9/2021(Estimated)
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried. And the error from you attempt using `[contains(text(), 'Estimated')]`.